# Octahedral facet solid angle

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, euclidean-geometry, solid-angle

I'm trying to get an equation for a solid angle of a segment of octahedron in the same vein as described in this article [cubemap-texel-solid-angle](http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2012/01/15/cubemap-texel-solid-angle/). I ended up having to integrate
$$\int \int \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+(1-x-y)^2)^\frac{3}{2}} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y$$ where $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$. That is, integral over a segment of a triangle mapped onto the sphere(one octant). Does anyone know how to integrate that?
[Subdivided polyhedrons by courtesy of Gavin Kistner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQR7z.png)

**Update**
Thanks to the general formula from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211287/how-to-find-out-the-solid-angle-subtended-by-a-tetrahedron-at-its-vertex/3305625#3305625):
$$\omega=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta\cos\gamma}{\sin\beta\sin\gamma}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\cos\gamma}
{\sin\alpha\sin\gamma}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos\gamma-\cos\alpha\cos\beta}{\sin\alpha\sin\beta}\right)$$

We can calculate a solid angle for all the triangles. Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/aschrein/ad2554b9c54a207f6dcfbe431b130d04) and the [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tlBXDd). The naive implementation is not numerically stable at small angles.

**Update** See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3343709)

Comment: I have to say it seems odd to me that this thing does double integration instead of using dot products et al and basic spherical trig.

Comment: @DanUznanski I wonder if this is applicable [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211287/how-to-find-out-the-solid-angle-subtended-by-a-tetrahedron-at-its-vertex)

Comment: That would help a lot.  Given that, you can simply split any quadrilaterals into two triangles and do the given calculation.

Comment: What are calling "a segment" for an octahedron ? This is not a usual term in this context. Are you refering to an edge, a facet ?

Comment: Sorry. By segment I meant some part of a facet. More specifically I'm looking for a solid angle of each triangle in a tessellated octahedron. Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: [solid-angle-tetrahedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211287/how-to-find-out-the-solid-angle-subtended-by-a-tetrahedron-at-its-vertex) seems to work. On CPU It gives the correct sum of angles, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aschrein/ad2554b9c54a207f6dcfbe431b130d04) however on GPU it tends to lose precision quickly, here is [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/tlBXDd)

Comment: @AntonSchreiner if that is your answer, then make it an Answer!  Answering your own question after some research is not only allowed but encouraged.

Comment: @DanUznanski I guess David K already nailed it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general problem I think you have described is to find the solid angle subtended at one vertex of a tetrahedron.

If we label the vertex in question $O$ and put it at the center of a unit sphere, then project the opposite face onto the sphere, we get a spherical triangle.
The lengths of the "sides" of that triangle are the angles $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ and $\gamma$ between the edges of the tetrahedron that meet at $O.$
The angles at the vertices of the spherical triangle are the dihedral angles $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ between the faces of the tetrahedron that meet at $O.$
The usual convention is we use the name $A$ for the angle between the sides of length $\beta$ and $\gamma,$
the name $B$ for the angle between the sides of length $\alpha$ and $\gamma,$
and the name $C$ for the angle between the sides of length $\alpha$ and $\beta.$

The solid angle at $O$ is then the area of the spherical triangle,
which in turn is equal to the *spherical excess* of that triangle, defined as
$$ E = A + B + C - \pi. $$

But the information that you seem to be assuming is that you know the three angles $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ and $\gamma.$
So the question becomes how to find $E$ in terms of those angles.

The spherical law of cosines says that
$$ \cos\alpha = \cos\beta \cos\gamma + \sin\beta \sin\gamma \cos A. $$
Solving for $A$ we get
$$ A = \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\alpha - \cos\beta \cos\gamma}
                          {\sin\beta \sin\gamma}\right) .$$

There are similar formulas involving the angles $B$ and $C,$ with the results
$$ B = \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\beta - \cos\alpha \cos\gamma}
                          {\sin\alpha \sin\gamma}\right) $$
and
$$ C = \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha \cos\beta}
                          {\sin\alpha \sin\beta}\right) .$$

As a result, one formula for the spherical excess is
\begin{align}
E &= \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\alpha - \cos\beta \cos\gamma}
                          {\sin\beta \sin\gamma}\right) \\
&\qquad
   + \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\beta - \cos\alpha \cos\gamma}
                          {\sin\alpha \sin\gamma}\right) \\
&\qquad
   + \arccos \left(\frac{\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha \cos\beta}
                          {\sin\alpha \sin\beta}\right) - \pi.
\end{align}

The formula shown in the question is a variation of this formula that can be obtained using the identity $\arccos(x) = \frac\pi2 - \arcsin(x).$

I would be suspicious of the numerical stability of this formula for very small spherical angles (that is, when you have divided your sphere into a very large number of triangular facets), because neither $\arccos(x)$ nor $\arcsin(x)$ is very accurate when $x$ is close to $1.$
You might be better off with another formula such as
$$
E = 2 \arctan\left(\frac{\tan\frac\alpha 2 \tan\frac\beta 2 \sin C}
                        {1 + \tan\frac\alpha 2 \tan\frac\beta 2 \cos C}\right),
$$
(from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Area_and_spherical_excess))
using formulas such as
$$ 
 \cos C = \frac{\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha \cos\beta}{\sin\alpha \sin\beta}
$$
and
$$ \sin C = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 C}. $$

This should be fine if the three angles of the triangle are approximately equal (as seems to be the case in your "octahedron"-based construction). If one of the angles is almost $180$ degrees and the other two are almost zero you might want to compute $\sin C$ differently.

Comment: Wow, the precision of your solution is much better. I updated the gist and the shadertoy.

Answer (score 1):

All 8 facets of an octaedron are alike and interchangeable.

Then, the looked for solid angle is

> $$\frac18(4\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm looking for the solid angle of a subdivided facet of an octahedron. Here is an [image](http://phrogz.net/CSS/Geodesics/VariousGeodesics_planar.png) for clarification.

Comment: If your subdivision is recursively using at each step the normal dropped from the center to the new set of facets (multiplying by 4 their numbers at each step), you will have equal solid angles all the time.  Therefore, the formula, instead of $\pi/2$ (the value I gave), will have to be divided by $4^n$

Comment: This depends on how you project the faces onto the sphere. I'm referring to the simplest scheme where you first subdivide a flat octant and then divide each vertex by its length. It's again the fault of my vague question. Here is an article where different projection schemes are described [link](http://donw.io/post/sphere-indexing/)

Comment: I understand why you need general _areas of spherical triangles_ (because your question about solid angles can be simply reformulated in these terms, the term "solid angle" being synonymous to that)